# I obliterated a ceramic SMD, how to find out what piece it is?

Tags: resistors, dc, surface-mount, repair

this is from a laser GRBL generic from China, 12v and 5v.

The neighbor SMD appears identical to the one that was cracked. The multimeter measured 1.0 mega and milliohms, I couldn't get a reading.

Do you know what is the piece and a good place to salvage, how should I proceed?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be one of the load capacitances of the crystal which appears to be "removed":

[image]

That and the one to its right have the same capacitance.

Carefully remove the other capacitor to the right, wait for it to cool down, and measure its capacitance with a good LCR meter. Should be a few to a few tens of picofarads (pF).

Find a same or closest value (e.g. if you measured 16 pF you can use 15 pF), same package capacitor, replace "both of them".

Don't forget to fit the crystal as well. It's  required for the MCU.

Comment: there don't appear to be any solder pads for a crystal. And the silk screen seems to be for a crystal module, which is not fitted - instead you have two caps. I would look up the MCU and see what is going on with those pins. Maybe they are using an internal CR oscillator instead, or something.

Comment: @danmcb Which is not fitted *anymore*: notice the solder fillets and sharp residue where leads used to be.

Comment: @danmcb if you look at the image again you can see the SMD HC-49 crystal pads and the silkscreen. Also the pads show that there "was" a crystal there which is either broken or removed by force.

Comment: ah ok, I see it. you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

I am 99% sure that if you slap down the least expensive/most popular HC49/U 16MHz crystal and an appropriate size NP0 22pF capacitor it will work fine.

There is nothing that requires extreme precision in timing in the GRBL controller and many use the Nano which does not even have a crystal (ceramic resonator only). So worrying about exact match of load capacitors is a waste of time and effort.

Answer (score 4):

These are loading capacitors for the crystal. Apparently the crystal has been ripped away as well. So the more tricky part is probably finding the right crystal.

What I would try to do:

- Find out what type of device the crystal is providing a clock for (looks like a micro-controller).
- Find out what type of crystal is required for that device (datasheet). Some datasheets already recommend values for the capacitors (usually 15pF'ish NP0/C0G).
- Replace the crystal and both the missing **and** the remaining capacitor with capacitors that are recommended in the crystal's or micro-controller's datasheet (in case the remaining capacitor is not the right one for the crystal you chose as replacement).

The main problem is maybe that micro-controllers often support multiple frequencies for external crystals. And there is probably no straight-forward way to find out which frequency is used in this application as this is typically programmed into firmware or into the micro-controllers configuration, respectively.

Maybe there is an evaluation board for this micro-controller. Instead of rolling a dice, I would probably go for the crystal that has been used in the evaluation board (as the designer of your board maybe did as well).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the exact value of that capacitor cannot be known.

Fortunately, that cap was a crystal loading capacitor for the Atmel CPU as shown.

As mentioned in another answer, you can remove the other crystal loading capacitor, as they generally, but not always, are two identical capacitors. The problem is, they are approximately in the 12 to 22 pF range, which makes them difficult to measure without a special tool capable of measuring such low range of capacitances.

In theory you could just put any NP0 type ceramic cap within that range and hope it works, but it will pull the crystal value away from the nominal. It might also work without the capacitor until you fix it.

Since the crystal is also missing, the MCU won't work at all without a crystal.

You could also buy a new crystal with known load capacitance requirement and buy two load capacitors that are suitable value for that crystal.

Again you need to know what frequency crystal the Atmel MCU, or rather, the firmware running on it expects.

Anyway, those caps are usually 5% NP0/C0G type ceramic caps.